# Further,let $\bar S$ denotes the closure of $S $.then which of the following statement is True

Tags: real-analysis

let $S \subset \mathbb{R} $ and $dS$ denote the set of points in $x$ in $\mathbb{R}$  such that every neighbhourhood of  $x$  contains some points  of  $S$ as  well as  some points  of complement of $S$. Further,let $\bar S$ denotes the  closure  of $S $.then  which of the following statement  is True

$a)$ $dQ = \mathbb{R}$

$b)$$d(\mathbb{R}\setminus T) =dT , T \subset \mathbb{R}$

$c)$$ d(T \cup V) =dT \cup dV.$  $T,V \subset \mathbb{R}$ , $T\cap V \neq \phi$

$d)$ $dT = \bar T \cap \overline{(\mathbb{R}\setminus T)}, T \subset \mathbb{R}$

## My Attempts :

option a) is  clearly True as boundary of $\mathbb{Q}$  is  $\mathbb{R}$

For  option $c)$  is false take  $T= [0,1]$, $V =[\frac{1}{2},2]$,then $T \cup V =[0,2]$ so $d(T \cup V) =\{0,2\}$ but $dT \cup dV =\{0,\frac{1}{2},1,2\} \neq \{0,2\}$

Im confuse about option b) and option d)

pliz help me

Any hints/solution will be aprreciated

thanks u

Comment: a might be "clearly true" (and it is) but you really need to explain why "boundary of Q" and "dQ" are synonyms. si you must explain why  the set of all points so that all neighborhoods contain both rationals and irrationals is the real numbers. (This could be acceptable. Every open integer contains rationals and irrationals so every real number has an open interval/neighborhood and round it with points both in and no in Q).

Comment: Both $b$ and $d$ are true. Just follow the definitions. Take any $x\in dT$ and see by definition why it must be in $d(\mathbb{R}\setminus T)$, same about the other direction.

Comment: For b think of what the definition says.  dT is the set of points in which every neighborhood has points in and not in.  R\T is the set of points not in.  So dR\T would be the set of points where every neighborhood has points that are not in and points that are not not in.  Not not in means in, doesn't it. So both dT and dR\T describe points with the same types of neighborhoods, right?

Comment: d. Talk it out. And use b). OverlineT = T+dT.  And overlineR\T= T +dR\T.  b) says dT and dR\T are the same.  So Overline T =T+dT and overline R\T =R\T+dT.  What do those have in common and what do the distinctly *not* have in common?

Comment: Try not to visualize this as a clear cut border.  Yes, the border of (1,3] is clearly {1,3} and even border of Q is R might be clear, but there can be some pretty hard to visualize sets coming up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

b) is clearly true, as the definition of boundary comes down to the same thing for a set and its complement (the complement of the complement is the original set).

d) is a reformulation of the definition as well.

Comment: thanks u henno sir